# How can I optimize this or is there a better way to do it?(HTML Syntax Highlighter)

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I have made a HTML syntax highlighter in C# and it works great, but there's one problem. First off It runs pretty fast because it syntax highlights line by line, but when I paste more than one line of code or open a file I have to highlight the whole file which can take up to a minute for a file with only 150 lines of code. I tried just highlighting visible lines in the richtextbox but then when I try to scroll I can't it to highlight the new visible text. Here is my code:(note: I need to use regex so I can get the stuff in between < & > characters)

Highlight Whole File:

```
  public void AllMarkup()
    {
        int selectionstart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;



        Regex rex = new Regex("<html>|</html>|<head.*?>|</head>|<body.*?>|</body>|<div.*?>|</div>|<span.*?>|</span>|<title.*?>|</title>|<style.*?>|</style>|<script.*?>|</script>|<link.*?/>|<meta.*?/>|<base.*?/>|<center.*?>|</center>|<a.*?>|</a>");
        foreach (Match m in rex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text))
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(m.Index, m.Value.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            richTextBox1.Select(selectionstart, -1);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
        }

        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = selectionstart;
    }


    private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LockWindowUpdate(richTextBox1.Handle);//Stops text from flashing flashing
            richTextBox1.Paste();
            AllMarkup();

        }finally { LockWindowUpdate(IntPtr.Zero); }
    }
```

I want to know if there's a better way to highlight this and make it faster or if someone can help me make it highlight only the visible text.

Please help. :) 
Thanks, Tanner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I agree with RCIX, but some more advise. Several small regex are usually faster than one large one. Using IndexOf is also much quicker than regex. And finally, parse it with a html parser and build the RTF text first, and then put it in the control.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with RCIX - you'll have a hard time overall with combining Regex and HTML parsing :)

If you're going for a high-quality solution that always highlights syntax properly, you're going to need a full-blown parser.  You can either use one that's already created, or you can create your own using a tool like [ANTLR](http://antlr.org).

The creators of ANTLR have already created an HTML parser grammar.  You can find it [here](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/HTML/html.g).

If you're looking for a pre-built one, here's a few I've found:

1. [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
2. [Majestic 12 HTML Parser](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php)
3. [SGML Reader](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SgmlReader)

I'm sure there are others -- this is a pretty common requirement.

Long story short, if this is anything but a simple, disposable project, I'd get a full-blown parser.  Otherwise, you can continue to try and hack it with Regex.